# Can't run .bat files properly (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, batch-file

Here is my `test.bat`

```
#!/bin/bash
#set the STRING variable
SET STRING=Hello World
#Print the contents of the variable to the screen
echo $STRING
pause
```

When I run test.bat on Windows 10 I get this output:

```
C:\Workspace\mcc-batch-jobs>#!/bin/bash
'#!' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Workspace\mcc-batch-jobs>#set the STRING variable
'#set' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Workspace\mcc-batch-jobs>SET STRING=Hello World

C:\Workspace\mcc-batch-jobs>#Print the contents of the variable to the screen
'#Print' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Workspace\mcc-batch-jobs>echo $STRING
$STRING

C:\Workspace\mcc-batch-jobs>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I can't figure it out. I've checked my PATH, installed cygwin, looked over several Stackoverflow posts, and can't seem to get the script to work. The script was created as a simple test and nothing more.

Comment: Must be the first time I see a `Windows batchfile` that starts with `#!/bin/bash`... Do you want that file to be run by cygwin?

Comment: I might have a bad understanding of the environments or running scripts on Mac vs Windows...I would just like to run the script through command prompt or powershell

Comment: I have removed your shell and bash tags as neither are relevant to your question.  5 lines: `@ECHO Off`,   `SET "STRING=Hello World"`,   `REM Print the contents of the variable to the screen`,   `ECHO %STRING%`,   `PAUSE`.

Comment: @Compo Thanks? lol.

Comment: Changing the extension of a bash script to `.bat` does not make it a valid batch file.

Comment: @BenVoigt A more thorough explanation or answer would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: How did you obtain this file? Why do you think it is a .bat file? It's a Linux shell script, not a Windows batch file.

Comment: You wrote a bash script, but named it `.bat` (a batch script, which is very different). What's the proper extension for a bash script?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm writing the file. I didn't 'obtain' the file, I just started writing it. I don't usually write on a Windows envrionment. I'll do some more research now.

Comment: @compo I'm not sure, if it's the bash tag, which was the wrong one. The shown script is bash but the file extension does not match.

Comment: @Josh: please clarify: do you want to use batch or bash?

Comment: @Stephan I'm on windows, so I'm assuming batch.

Comment: Why then use bash commands and even install cygwin? For batch, bookmark [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/), a great reference of available batch commands.

Comment: Note that Windows has several "script" types built-in (good old command and powershell, syntaxes are wildly different and not interchangeable) and that contrary to unix-y operating systems, like MacOS, Windows almost entirely decides what it's going to do with a file based on the file's extension.

Comment: @fvu Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment, this is a batch file for Windows, *(it usually has a `.cmd` extension but  may use `.bat` instead)*:

```bat
@ECHO Off
SET "STRING=Hello World"
REM Print the contents of the variable to the screen
ECHO %STRING%
PAUSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I see I was making quite a few fundamental errors writing scripts on Windows. Chosen as the best answer for a clear and concise example